# MySql remote connection from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have allowed remote connections to mysql. I can successully connect from the console of another machine.

I have some php files on another server but I cant connect to the same mysql db from php.

This is the way I'm doing it:

```
mysql_pconnect("theipaddress","username","password")
               or die("Unable to connect to db server");
```

Now bear in mind I am using the same creds which I successfully used in the console. I even tried putting the port after the ip but no joy.

Any ideas?

Comment: The exception would normally tell you if it can't connect, authentication or some other problem.

Comment: Are your access permissions restricted by ip? Perhaps your server with php is not allowed to connect but the machine you connect from with the console was.

Comment: Theres no error except for the die output... Also I did a grant permissions username@'%'

Comment: Do what Bensik suggested, replace the string inside `die()` with `mysql_error()` plus enable error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: The mysql_error() is Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: Excellent! now we copy `Lost connection to MySQL server during query` and paste it in Google.

Comment: The only things I see on google relating to that error is for large requests that time out. This problem is happening instantly just on initial connect.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried a non-persistent connection? ie using `mysql_connect()` instead of `mysql_pconnect()`

Comment: Yeah tried that and its the same....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a user in MySQL who is allowed to connect from % (any host) (see manual for details).

Have you selinux installed? Maybe selinux is not allowing apache to make remote connections? If yes, type:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Comment: Do you mean the apache server could be preventing the php from accessing a remote DB ?

Comment: Setlinux or iptables can prevent php from accessing remote db. Maybe your user is allowed to connect to the remote mysql server but the apache user not (php is running as apache user)

Comment: Isnt the user specified in the mysql_pconnect  ? Should I create a user called apache on the mysql server?